# Regex: match partial string up to character unless another is encountered

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I've found multiple posts with negative lookaheads, but I can't seem to make it work for this particular use case.

I have multiple lines with one of the following 4 patterns (and possibly more than 2 options):

```
text [option1/option2] text
text] [option1/option2] more text
text [option1/option2] [text
text] [option1/option2] [text
```

Looking for a regex (more likely multiple: one for left and one for right) that will match only the single-bracketed text (in bold below):

text [option1/option2] text

**text]** [option1/option2] more text

text [option1/option2] **[text**

**text]** [option1/option2] **[text**

Making multiple passes over the lines is fine. Also, this is Python, so if there's a completely different way, I'm open to suggestions. This are just strings in a list.

Thanks in advance
-mS

Comment: *I can't seem to make it work*  - but *what* did you try? *What* did not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `(^\w+\])|(\[\w+$)`

**`(^\w+\])`** - match `\w` one and unlimited times `^` at start of a line followed by `\]`.

**`|`**        - OR

**`(\[\w+$)`** - match `\w` one and unlimited times preceded by `\[` at the end of a line `$`.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Dk2KO/1)

Comment: Much easier to read and works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to match this.
What do you need with the look around assertions though ?

`(text\] (?:\[option1/option2\])(?: \[text)?|(?:\[option1/option2\]) \[text)`

=

```
 (
      text \] [ ]
      (?: \[ option1/option2 \] )
      (?: [ ] \[ text )?
   |  (?: \[ option1/option2 \] )
      [ ] \[ text
 )
```

see  https://regex101.com/r/HxY4Uv/1

---

You can wrap capture groups around the 3 forms to see which matched
so you don't have to post process string's.

`(text\]) (?:\[option1/option2\]) (\[text)?|(?:\[option1/option2\]) (\[text)`

see https://regex101.com/r/CqzZID/1

Answer (score 0):

following regex will match your lines as you want:

`(^[^\[\]]*?\])|(\[(?!.*?\]).*)`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AVHWx0/4)

also `(^[^\[\]]*?\])|(\[[^\[\]]*$)` must work for which is without using look forward and simpler. you can split regex to `(^[^\[\]]*?\])` and `(\[[^\[\]]*$)` ,then match each one against line to use matching group.

Comment: Nailed it with this one. This is perfect. I need to go through it to see what it's doing, but works great. Thank you.